# Doubts related to SIM300 power rating and its configuration?

Tags: microcontroller, datasheet, gsm, sim

I just started reading SIM300 data sheet (http://probots.co.in/Manuals/SIM300.pdf). Under the section 5.3 Power supply ratings.I have few following doubts

i) peak supply current transmission  is mentioned as 2A(typical) - is it means that my power supply to SIM300  should capable of delivering  2A?

ii)Average supply current :Ivbat for data mode has two configurations 
      1-DATA mode, GPRS (3 Rx,2Tx)   2-DATA mode, GPRS (4 Rx,1Tx).what's the usage of this two modes and how to configure this.I looking for GPRS (4 Rx,1Tx) mode  because of its low current consumption ?

Answer (score 1):

i, Yes, it is.

ii, It depends on your need. 2Tx or 1Tx.